# Conditional redirection with nginx, if the directory is available?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Is there is a possibility than I can rewrite/ or redirect to different a URL when a certain folder exists via Nginx?

For example:

www.abc.com/feedback (normal URL)

But when there is a certain directory exists, I want above URL to rewrite/redirect as follows:

www.abc.com/**xyz/**feedback (conditional base in Nginx, if directory exists rewrite/redirect)

Comment: You can determine of a directory exists using `if (-d $request_filename) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, @RichardSmith, (thumsup), would be good if you put it as an answer I will accept it.